# process with UID postgres eats CPU

Tags: postgresql, centos7, cpu-usage

I am facing with cpu load issue causing by postgresql server.

Here is top output:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                   
   8267 postgres  20   0  268508   4816    868 S 160.0  0.1   4785:37 x3307700177                                                                                                               
      1 root      20   0   43296   3120   1852 S   0.0  0.1   0:52.91 systemd
```

Can somebody explain what is the that weird process and what can be done for decreasing cpu usage by that process?
I've tried to find out what that process is but no luck, google told me nothing.

```
PostgreSQL-9.2.23
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it takes a while, can you `select query from pg_stat_activity where pid = 8267`

Comment: @VaoTsun
`postgres=# SELECT query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid=8267;
 query 
-------
(0 rows)

`

Comment: Check out if that is a child of the postmaster (via the `PPID`). Judging from the name, I'd say it isn't (unless you have an extension installed that starts background worker processes with such a weird name). Use `lsof` to see what executable it is and what files it accesses. Use `strace` to figure out what it is doing.

Comment: PPID=PID and x3307700177 is executable by itself. `strace -p 8267
strace: Process 8267 attached
epoll_wait(14, [], 1024, 179)           = 0
epoll_wait(14, [], 1024, 90)            = 0
epoll_wait(14, [], 1024, 500)           = 0
epoll_wait(14, [], 1024, 301)           = 0`
lsof showed that 14 is `x33077001 8267 postgres   14u  a_inode     0,9        0     5983 [eventpoll]`

Comment: so what was it? some bitcoin calculation? did youfind out?

Comment: @VaoTsun Unfortunately It is still unknown for me what that process is and how to deal with it.

Comment: did you at least `sudo find / -name x3307700177` as sudo user?..

Comment: @VaoTsun   It has been located in postgres data directory. Finally i've upgraded to 10.1 version and that solved the issue.